# ReactJS + AWS API Gateway : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

This is my first post. I am new to ReactJS and AWS, I keep getting a CORS error when I try to connect my form.js file with an AWS API by using axios.post() function. I have tried every possible thing in the last 3 days, with no luck whatsoever! I don't know what I am doing wrong, I tried enabling CORS in AWS API Gateway, no luck there either. Can someone please help!!

Here's my form.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      dob: '',
      major: '',
      univ: '',
      desiredcareer: '',
      typeofopp: '',
      collegestressor: '',
      stresslevel: ''
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleDOBChange = this.handleDOBChange.bind(this);
    this.handleMajorChange = this.handleMajorChange.bind(this);
    this.handleUnivChange = this.handleUnivChange.bind(this);
    this.handleDesiredCareerChange = this.handleDesiredCareerChange.bind(this);
    this.handleTypeOfOppChange = this.handleTypeOfOppChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCollegeStressorChange = this.handleCollegeStressorChange.bind(this);
    this.handleStressLevelChange = this.handleStressLevelChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleNameChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleDOBChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      dob: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleMajorChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      major: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleUnivChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      univ: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleDesiredCareerChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      desiredcareer: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleTypeOfOppChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      typeofopp: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleCollegeStressorChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      collegestressor: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleStressLevelChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      stresslevel: event.target.value
    });
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { name,dob,major,univ,desiredcareer,typeofopp,collegestressor,stresslevel } = this.state;
    await axios.post(
      "https://4hpnc7h0fa.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Test/enterdetails/jujiPutUserDetails",
      { key1: `${name}`,
        key2: `${dob}`,
        key3: `${major}`,
        key4: `${univ}`,
        key5: `${desiredcareer}`,
        key6: `${typeofopp}`,
        key7: `${collegestressor}`,
        key8: `${stresslevel}`
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            onChange={this.handleNameChange}
            value={this.state.name}
          />

          <label>Date Of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY):</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="dob"
            onChange={this.handleDOBChange}
            value={this.state.dob}
          />

          <label>Major:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="major"
            onChange={this.handleMajorChange}
            value={this.state.major}
          />

          <label>University:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="univ"
            onChange={this.handleUnivChange}
            value={this.state.univ}
          />

          <label>Desired Career Field:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="desiredcareer"
            onChange={this.handleDesiredCareerChange}
            value={this.state.desiredcareer}
          />

          <label>Type Of Opportunity Wanted:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="typeofopp"
            onChange={this.handleTypeOfOppChange}
            value={this.state.typeofopp}
          />

          <label>College Stressor Factor:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="collegestressor"
            onChange={this.handleCollegeStressorChange}
            value={this.state.collegestressor}
          />

          <label>Stress Level (1-10):</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="stresslevel"
            onChange={this.handleStressLevelChange}
            value={this.state.stresslevel}
          />

          <button type="submit">Submit Information</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://4hpnc7h0fa.execute-api.us-west- 
2.amazonaws.com/Test/enterdetails/jujiPutUserDetails' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to 
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access- 
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

xhr.js:155 POST https://4hpnc7h0fa.execute-api.us-west- 
2.amazonaws.com/Test/enterdetails/jujiPutUserDetails net::ERR_FAILED

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:69)
```

Update:

Here is my Lambda Function Code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "us-west-2"});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Processing...");
    const params = {
        Item: {
            userID: context.awsRequestId,
            name: JSON.stringify(event.key1),
            dob: JSON.stringify(event.key2),
            major: JSON.stringify(event.key3),
            univ: JSON.stringify(event.key4),
            desiredcareer: JSON.stringify(event.key5),
            typeofopp: JSON.stringify(event.key6),
            collegestressor: JSON.stringify(event.key7),
            stresslevel: JSON.stringify(event.key8)
        },
        TableName: "jujiuseronboarding"
    };
    const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://localhost:3000/'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify('Item Added Successfully!'),
  };
    
    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    })
};
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Is your API backed by Lambda?

Comment: I have used the same stack and got the same issue last time. There are couple factors can cause it. Need more information before answering the question

Comment: @hephalump Yes it is!

Comment: @NghiaDo What other info do you need? Lambda function definition?

Comment: Your Lambda response needs to include the CORS headers...

Comment: @hephalump It does! still doesn't work :(

Comment: Because it is localhost:3000 change it to “*”

Comment: Changed it to '*', same errors exactly

Comment: You also have to actually send the response.

Comment: Oh! how do I do that?

Comment: It works fine when I test the Lambda function by itself, entries get added into the DynamoDB table. Even when I test the API, it works! Only while trying to submit the form in react (form.js), a CORS error pops up :(

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are not sending the headers in the response. So I have commented callback in else statement of Dynamodb put function and have put a callback at the end for sending the response with headers (which is basically response variable)

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "us-west-2"});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Processing...");
    const params = {
        Item: {
            userID: context.awsRequestId,
            name: JSON.stringify(event.key1),
            dob: JSON.stringify(event.key2),
            major: JSON.stringify(event.key3),
            univ: JSON.stringify(event.key4),
            desiredcareer: JSON.stringify(event.key5),
            typeofopp: JSON.stringify(event.key6),
            collegestressor: JSON.stringify(event.key7),
            stresslevel: JSON.stringify(event.key8)
        },
        TableName: "jujiuseronboarding"
    };
    const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' // changed this
    },
    body: JSON.stringify('Item Added Successfully!'),
  };
    
    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            // callback(null, data);
        }
    });
    
    callback(null, response);

};
```

Comment: Hello! I tried adding this code to my Lambda Function, and also enabled cors in AWS API Gateway, CORS error still shows up :( Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: Glad I could help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if CORS is enabled in API Gateway console ?

For any update request ( POST , PUT etc), API Gateway expects OPTIONS to be enabled for pre-flight requests. Can you please check if it is enabled?

If this is not enabled, request invocation will fail with CORS error. This OPTIONS is not mandatory for GET requests.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

https://enable-cors.org/server_awsapigateway.html

If the CORS is enabled , can you please test and see if it is working following the steps mentioned there?

Comment: Hey! I tried your links, and along with a modification in my lambda function, I was able to get it up and running! Thank you so much for your answer! :D